# Insert row dynamically in html using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using below the code to insert a  row dynamically in html table.

```
var newRow = jQuery('<tr><td><input style="width:200px" type="text" name="designation' +
counter + '"/></td><td><input style="width:200px" type="text" id="start_date'+ counter +'" name="start_date' +
        counter + '"/></td><td><input style="width:200px" id="end_date'+ counter +'" type="text" name="end_date' +
        counter + '"/></td></tr>');
    jQuery('table.authors-list').append(newRow);
```

This code works fine. The row is always inserted as last row. But i need to insert the row just before the last row. I mean if the table has 3 rows, then new row should be in 3rd place the row which was there in 3rd place should be moved to last. How can i achieve this? Please help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`.before()`](http://api.jquery.com/before/) method here like :

```
jQuery('table.authors-list tr:last').before(newRow);
```

- `tr:last` will get the last row in the `authors-list` table.
- `.before()`  will insert the new row before the last one.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('table tr:last').before($('<tr>....</tr>'))
```